# Why i cant scroll in textview android?

Tags: android, textview, android-scrollview

I'm beginner in android and i write simple apllication to show a simple text in textView in android studio,but when i write a big text in textView,textview can't scroll,my xml file is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/MAINLABEL"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

what happen?

Comment: How you want to scroll. `Horizontal` or `Vertical`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/MAINLABEL"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I don't think this is best answer... you don't need to add `ScrollView`

Answer (score 5):

### Horizontal Scrolling:

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Horizontal scroll view will work now"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

### Vertical Scrolling:

You don't need to use a `ScrollView` actually.

Just set the

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"

android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

properties of your `TextView` in your layout's xml file.

Then use:

`yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

in your code.

It will helps you. Thanks.

Comment: In my case, just the `setMovementMethod` did the trick for a vertical scroll (with `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"`).

Answer (score 0):

If `TextView` isn't scrolling automatically , wrap it inside a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) in order to make it scroll.

From the [documentations](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) , The TextView class also takes care of its own scrolling, so does not require a ScrollView, but using the two together is possible to achieve the effect of a text view within a larger container.

Another answer provided by Paresh will work but surely `maxLines` requires you to enter an arbitrary number; this isn't something that will work for every screen size and font size i guess. So it is simpler to just wrap it with a `ScrollView`, meaning you don't have to add any further XML attributes or code (like setting the movement method).

Comment: You don't need to use a ScrollView actually. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31668039/1318946

Comment: *From the documentations , The TextView class also takes care of its own scrolling, so does not require a ScrollView, but using the two together is possible to achieve the effect of a text view within a larger container.* That's why your first line is wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll your text horizontally then wrap your `TextView` inside `HorizontalScrollView` or if you want to scroll your `TextView` vertically then wrap it into `ScrollView`.

**For Horizontal scrolling**

```
 <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/yourid"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

**For Vertical scrolling**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/yourid"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You don't need to use a ScrollView actually. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31668039/1318946